# vb.net javascript errors using IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I want to use Bootstrap to format a home page in a vb.net web form project.
I have included the css and js files

```
<link href="./Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="./Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

When I run this in chrome, it works fine.
But when run in IE11 I get the following error messages:

Exception was thrown at line 1361, column 4 in http://localhost:59200/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1379, column 4 in http://localhost:59200/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

I have ensured the Bootstrap and jquery have been updated with the NuGet manager.
I have also get the same result when I link to the remote files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Compatibilty mode does not make a difference on the eror messages, but it does for the resulting formating.

I have searched for the specific error message, and lots of generic statements, but none give a resolution for me.
Any suggestions please ?